# Polymer - Iron Ajax - How to Handle Error Response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, polymer

I have a standard `iron-ajax` element that sends a `login` request with an `email` and `password` to the backend.

```
<iron-ajax
     id="postLoginForm"
     method="POST"
     verbose
     url="../../login"
     content-type="application/json"
     handle-as="json"
     last-error="{{lastError}}"
     last-response="{{lastResponse}}"
     on-response="_handleLoginResponse"></iron-ajax>
```

My `_handleLoginResponse` is this, which works fine btw:

```
_handleLoginResponse: function (event) {
    console.log(event.detail.response);
},
```

This is **always** the response I am getting from the server:

`{"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}`

The problem is now, that the `_handleLoginResponse` method is *only* called, when the **status code** of the response is `200`.

But if the login failes, the servers sends a **status code** of `422 Unprocessable Entity` that does not trigger the `_handleLoginResponse` method. Though the response contains the above mentioned `json` string.

#### What I would like to do:

I would like to send the request without credentials. If the request successively fails I receive a response with a status code that is not 200. I want to display the errors on the page.

But I don't know how to access the response, if the `_handleLoginResponse` method does not trigger, when the status code is not 200.

How do I trigger the `_handleLoginResponse` method, when I get a `422` status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 4** and 5** are error codes. This means you might also have to listen to iron-ajax `error` event.

Comment: I am getting 200 even in that case _handleLoginResponse does not execute